# Problem in solving a simple looking integral.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find, 
$$
\int e^x(\cot x - \sec^2 x)dx \tag*{(1)}
$$
I tried the integration by parts method, and that did not seem to work.

Upon further investigation, I noticed that I could not solve $\int e^x \cot x dx$ too.

I inserted the problem in **WolframAlpha** and got the solution in terms of **hypergeometric series** [see here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex+cot+x&x=0&y=0).

I entered the original question and got the answer in the terms of hypergeometric series.

---

My questions are,

1. How do I solve $(1)$? [WolframAlpha only gives the result, I want to see the steps].
2. How do I learn to solve integrals using hypergeometric series? Please suggest some resources or tutorials.
3. How do I identify if a particular problem needs the use of the hypergeometric seres?

---

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you. $\bowtie$

Comment: Did it occur to you to [enter the whole problem in Wolframalpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5Ex+%28cot+x+-+sec%5E2+x%29+dx&x=0&y=0)?

Comment: What is the original question that you received? Was it a definite integral?

Comment: @KennyLau made some edits. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @KennyLau The original question is $(1)$ above. The original question also has been answered in terms of **hypergeometric series** by wolfram alpha.